# Save webpage that has updated content via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, save, basecamp

Is there a way to save a webpage that has had it's content updated via an ajax request? I need to save basecamp message threads but can't export as I am not the account owner. As expected, the original source will only save the original content and if i try to use the following javascript command:

```
javascript:'<xmp>' + window.document.body.outerHTML+ '</xmp>'
```

only the body is shown. I would need the more than just the body content, as the headers contain the CSS files for easier reading.

Anyone know what to do?

Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

To get the inner HTML of the `<html>` element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.documentElement

Comment: I modified it to use outerHTML so I could get the full page, but thanks!